# Drupal-- How to place an image in Panels 3 panels and mini-panels, w/o views or nodes?

Tags: image, drupal-6, drupal-panels

Is it possible, through any modular functionality, to insert an image into a (mini-)panel, either through token replacement, or through an upload dialog, or through a file selection menu?

Do I have to use views?  Do I have to create nodes?

Would the best way be to make a panel node, and then embed it in a mini-node, if I want a block-like panel that can be placed on multiple pages?

I want to build a site with images in a particular layout as a small block, and make it very easy for my client to change those images in the future.  I can think of some other ways to make this work, but it's driving me crazy that there seems to be no way to simply PUT an image in a mini-panel without having to upload it and hard-code an image tag.

And since my client knows no HTML, coding it this way makes it un-helpful for him.  And this mini-panel block is going to be used on a number of pages, and needs to be easily modified.

I have been googling for about 45 minutes, and come up with nothing useful.

EDIT:  OR EVEN just put ONLY one image from an image field w/ multiple values in a panel region on a panel node?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. Get images in Drupal (IamgeAPI, ImageCache, CCK, Image node etc. OR CCK field with external image URL). Anyway you will end up with nodes that contain images. Use Views to display those nodes in a block. Use Nodequeue to control order of images with drag-and-drop UI or make some cook taxonomy/flag system. Put this block anywhere you want.

Comment: That's a good idea, except creating nodes is exactly what I wanted to avoid.  I should have been clearer.  I was looking for a way to just insert a single solitary image into a piece of panel content, without using views or anything where needless nodes are created.